# Ubuntu laptop screen + external hdmi screen

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu on a Dell  Inspiron n7110 laptop. When I try to connect to my external monitor with HDMI, things just fall apart.

Both monitors are Dell products with max resolution of 1600x900.

All windows get stretched out and mouse clicks are offset to right:

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

How can I correct the output of my displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly fixed this but if anyone stumbles around for this, here are the things I did:

- Reinstalled nvidia drivers, downloaded latest ones
- Changed all from "auto" to some other value in Nvidia X server settings
- Downloaded CompizConfig(didnt do anything here)
- Spammed fn + f1 keys
- When not in mirror mode spammed Start + P key

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when mirroring my laptop screen to my television. I just adjusted the resolution until it looked good.

Comment: They both are set to 1600x900. The launcher and everything else is ok, just the windows are screwed up. Also Mirrored mode works ok, but I dont want to use mirror mode